# Show package contents from command line

Tags: terminal

When working at the terminal, I often use the `open .` command to open a finder window showing the current working directory. But if the current directory is actually a package, like a `.app` application or a `.vmwarevm` virtual machine, `open .` launches the application or the virtual machine instead.

How can I open a finder window showing the contents of a specified package?

I’ve tried `open -A /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app .`, but that didn’t work.

Comment: Not at a Mac to test, but have you tried simply using `cd /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app`?  If it doesn't work, I'll remove the comment.

Comment: I'd wager a guess `open -a Finder .` doesn't work because when you double click on an App Bundle within Finder, it launches the app :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `open -R` for the first file in the bundle would work even if the bundle doesn't have a `Contents` directory:

```
reveal() (
  shopt -s nullglob
  for f; do
    a=("$f"/*)
    [[ -d $f && ${#a} != 0 ]] && open -R -- "${a[0]}" || open -R -- "$f"
  done
)
```

It might be easier to just type `open -R` and the path of some file inside the bundle though. You can bind `menu-complete` in `.inputrc` to make it easier to insert the path of the first file.

Answer (score 12):

You can simply `cd` into the package to open it in Terminal, then `open Contents` to open the contents in Finder.

For example, to open the contents of Safari.app in Finder, you can run the following:

```
cd /Applications/Safari.app
open Contents
```

Comment: Nope, not all packages have a `Contents` folder—`.vmwarevm` virtual machines sure don’t.

Comment: [Just files](http://pastebin.com/wbgVnXeA).

Comment: Another kind of bundle with no `Contents` folder is the `.xcodeproj` bundle. You can get an example [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/tarballs/Chess/Chess-300.22.tar.gz).

Comment: The *Contents* bit is just an example, performing a `cd` into the .app file is what you are looking for, regardless of the app bundles eventual contents.

Answer (score 1):

```
open -R *
```

opens the package in Finder. But beware: it also selects every contained file and folder. In general this might be OK for you as most of the times it's just `Contents`.

Looks like this:
[image: Schalalalalala]

Comment: Opening * seems like a very bad idea, especially without cautioning people on what it would do in the wrong directory (and how would someone that doesn't get directories even know which one they are in). Should this perhaps be a comment on [this other answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/103355/5472)?

Comment: @bmike I guess you forgot the -R option...

Answer (score 0):

```
open -R .
```

From

```
man open
```

-R, --reveal        Selects in the Finder instead of opening.

Answer (score -2):

From the finder, right click on the application and choose 'Show Contents". The opens the app and you can then navigate thru the enclosed folders.